# Name of a standard for time representation in milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime, unix-timestamp, epoch, milliseconds

I'm looking for the name of the standard for time, represented in milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC. We can get one calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Java. For example when we are talking about the same time, represented in seconds - we use term [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). It would be great if you provide a link to standard in the answer.

Comment: Why you required name?

Comment: i think`Epoch`, also known as `Unix timestamps`,

Comment: I think `Epoch time` also known as `Unix timestamp` is the amount of the time elapsed since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. It can be represented in seconds as well as milliseconds

Comment: I always call it “milliseconds since the epoch”. I understand “Unix time” as seconds since the epoch, so this is not exactly the same thing.

Comment: I don't think so there's a unique name for this. "Unix time in milliseconds" is good.

Comment: The [documentation of the `java.time.Instant` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) repeatedly uses “milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z”.

Comment: http://currentmillis.com uses “milliseconds since epoch” and “milliseconds since Unix Epoch”. The “Unix” qualification is probably useful for precision in some contexts.

Comment: It is required for project documentation. I thought there is a separate standard for it. But 'Unix time in milliseconds' will be enough. Thank you all. This question is **closed**

Comment: Can you please share an example, I don't think I have understood the question

Comment: Please don’t close the question. It could be interesting to other readers for a long future. There is no reason to prohibit further answers for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Whats called for the microseconds since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC?

Answer (score 2):

In the [GNU Linux documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) it is called:

> seconds since the epoch

Extrapolating you could call it milliseconds since the epoch.